# Apache attempting to load from /var/cache for munin

Tags: apache

I'm trying to get the Munin webpage working under Apache2 via SSL on Debian Etch.  My config for the website is:

**NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80**

```
<VirtualHost www.mydomain.org:80>
ServerName www.mydomain.org
...
  <Directory /var/www/https>
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost www.mydomain.org:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/https/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/blah
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/blah
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
...
<LOCATION /munin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Munin Users"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/auth-files/munin
    <limit GET PUT POST>
        require valid-user
    </limit>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</LOCATION>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Munin is configured to use the directory and the files are created and refereshed in the proper location.  I can go to https://www.mydomain.org/munin/, enter a username and password, and see the top page fine.  But when I try to drill down to the actual information, I get a 404 error:

Not Found

The requested URL /munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/apache_accesses.html was not found on this server.

The URL listed is the same URL that's in the URL of the browser window.  But when I look in the error log, I see:

```
File does not exist: /var/cache/munin/www/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/apache_accesses.html, referer: https://www.mydomain.org/munin/localdomain/index.html
```

The index.html file lists the file name as localdomain/localhost.localdomain/apache_accesses.html.

I do not have the cache module loaded:

```
root@etch:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ls
alias.conf        authz_default.load    autoindex.load  dir.conf      mime.load         reqtimeout.conf  ssl.load  alias.load        authz_groupfile.load  cgi.load        dir.load      negotiation.conf  reqtimeout.load  status.conf    auth_basic.load   authz_host.load       dav.load        env.load      negotiation.load  rewrite.load     status.load     auth_digest.load  authz_user.load       dav_fs.conf     include.load  php5.conf         setenvif.conf     authn_file.load   autoindex.conf        dav_fs.load     mime.conf     php5.load         setenvif.load
```

I do not have any directives to enable caching in my apache config:

```
root@etch:/etc/apache2# grep -i cache *
apache2.conf:#SSLSessionCache dbm:/var/cache/apache2/ssl_cache
apache2.conf:SSLSessionCache none
```

(The dbm cache line is commented out and I've restarted apache numerous times.)

```
root@etch:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# grep -i cache *
```

(zero lines returned.)

So why in the heck is apache trying to load the files from the /var/cache directory rather than the /var/www/https/munin directory?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for certain how it works on Debian, but the Ubuntu package for munin creates a config file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/munin`.

This config file specifies an alias for `/munin` : `Alias /munin /var/cache/munin/www`

`/var/cache/munin/www` is the default htmldir value for recent munin versions.